# Difference in running a app inside docker and without docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes

What is advantage of using docker in local machine for running app?
And difference without using do docker.

Comment: Reproducibility. No more "works on my machine". Furthermore, we can deploy all our dependencies (relational database, document-based database, graph-database, messaging-system, ....) )through docker (e.g. through a [docker-compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/). This also eases development.

Comment: There are a lot of advantages: 
1) You can easily install few versions of different software without any collisions (e.g. 10 versions of MongoDB).
2) As previous commentator said - it creates isolated environment similar to your production (the only difference is the actual number of resources, such as CPU/GPU/RAM/etc.).
3) Easy setup for new developers (no need to manually install each separate tool and resolve issues with installations/configuration/etc.).
4) Ability to quickly deploy test environments, or new servers, or deploy this app on your brand new laptop)).

Answer (score 1):

Reproducibility. No more "works on my machine".

Furthermore, we can deploy all our dependencies (relational database, document-based database, graph-database, messaging-system, ....) through docker (e.g. through a [docker-compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) and thus eases development.

Another advantage is that - in case we deploy to a container-based environment - we can use the exact same images used in production and thus improve dev-prod-parity.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of advantages:

1. You can easily install few versions of different software without any collisions (e.g. 10 versions of MongoDB).
2. As previous commentator said - it creates isolated environment similar to your production (the only difference is the actual number of resources, such as CPU/GPU/RAM/etc.).
3. Easy setup for new developers (no need to manually install each separate tool and resolve issues with installations/configuration/etc.).
4. Ability to quickly deploy test environments, or new servers, or deploy this app on your brand new laptop)).